Color in beamer acting unpredictably
In Beamer I would like to use a specific color I created within a colorbox like this:
\setbeamercolor{my color}{fg=blue}

\begin{frame}{Colorbox}
    \colorbox{\usebeamercolor[fg]{my color}}{Lorem ipsum}
\end{frame}

This results in an error: Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition. \new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
Using the color like this works fine:
\begin{frame}{Colorbox}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{my color}Lorem ipsum}
\end{frame}

I figured out that the following code:
\setbeamercolor{my color}{fg=blue}

\begin{frame}{Colorbox}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{my color}
    \colorbox{my color.fg}{Lorem ipsum}
\end{frame}

Does work, but I thought that was quite odd. Also, the Beamer User Guide discourages this (in fact, this workaround comes from the guide). I would prefer to be able to use \usebeamercolor directly. What am I doing wrong?

Beamer colours and, let's call them xcolor colours are not the same. You can't use a beamer colour as argument if \colorbox, you need to use an xcolor colour there. As you figured out, you can access the xcolor version of a beamer colour with e.g. my color.fg.

Instead of your second code fragment, I'd suggest \begin{frame} \frametitle{Colorbox}     {\usebeamercolor[fg]{my color}Lorem ipsum} \end{frame}, otherwise your text will be interpreted as frame subtitle.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the beamer documentation says "The optional ⟨title⟩ is detected by an opening brace, that is, if the first thing in the frame is an opening
brace then it is assumed that a frame title follows. Likewise, the optional ⟨subtitle⟩ is detected the same way, that is, by an opening brace following the ⟨title⟩."

Yes, that's why your Lorem Lipsum is interpreted as subtitle.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Oh, I see what you mean. Thanks for the improvement, but that was just me being too quick with my MWE.

That wans't you being too quick, that was you using that terrible \begin{frame}{frametitle} syntax. Better avoid it to avoid such problems.

You are not doing anything wrong. \colorbox isn't a beamer macro and thus expects, let's call it, an xcolor colour (I'm aware that xcolour didn't invent the colours, but calling it color colour would be even more confusing...).
As you've discovered, you can access the underlying xcolor colours of a beamer colour with <colourname>.fg and <colourname>.bg (the beamer colour needs to be used somewhere before this to make sure that the underlying xcolor colours exist).
If you'd like to use beamer colours without manually accessing the underlying xcolour colours, you could use a beamer macro like beamercolorbox:
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{my color}{fg=red,bg=green}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Colorbox}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=3cm]{my color}
Lorem ipsum
\end{beamercolorbox}

\colorbox{my color.fg}{Lorem Lipsum}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



\begin{frame}     \frametitle{Colorbox}     \colorbox{my color.fg}{Lorem Lipsum} \end{frame} 
Using just that (together with the color in preamble) results in an error "undefined color 'my color.fg'"

@Texnicallyausername the beamer colours need to be uses somewhere before this to make sure that the underlying xcolor colours exist

What do you mean exactly with being used somewhere? Should I just throw in a \usebeamercolor{my color} somewhere? That would be a bit annoying if I would have to do that with every color I create.

@Texnicallyausername You can directly use the beamer colour when you define it or use xcolor colours. Unless you use your colours to define things which expect a beamer colour, e.g. beamercolorboxes, there isn't really an advantage in using them.

I should specify that I'm defining the beamercolor inside the colortheme of a theme and I'm using the color within the outertheme of that same theme. Hence, I benefit from using a beamercolor. What is still not clear to me is what the "best practice" method would be of using the xcolor version of it, without needlessly "using it" just to unlock the xcolor version

You cannot use the xcolour version if you haven't used the beamer colour before. Thus this isn't a question about best practise, that's just what has to be done.

I see. I've accepted your answer. Although it is not ideal, if this is the way it should be done and it works, then that's it. Thanks for your help!

@Texnicallyausername You're welcome!
